# How to write a MySQL select query to find a user with a php crypt() password?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I've got a SQL user table where users passwords have been stored using php crypt() function, without salt.
They have been inserted into the table by a php script using this kind of code :

```
$uncrypted_pw = 'password';
$crypted_pw = crypt($uncrypted_pw);
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO user (pw) VALUES ('".$crypted_pw."')";
```

Now, I would like to make a select SQL query to find a user by his password.
Something like that :

```
$uncrypted_pw = 'password';
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE pw = '".$uncrypted_pw."'";
```

Of course, It won't work like that : I need to encrypt the password string in the query, like It was when inserted.
So my question is : Is there a SQL function to do that ?

I tried some SQL function like 'ENCRYPT' :

```
$uncrypted_pw = 'password';
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE pw = ENCRYPT('".$uncrypted_pw."')";
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for your help.

JG

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: _Big Note_ Hashing (which is what crypt does) and Encryption are not the same thing

Comment: `I would like to make a select SQL query to find a user by his password`...why?? Your application should never need to do anything with the user's password. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to use SimpleSAMLphp. It's configuration needs a SQL Select Query using username and password values in where clause.

Comment: UNless you are using a very old version of PHP the above code generates errors anyway. https://3v4l.org/8QJXg

Comment: `It's configuration needs a SQL Select Query using username and password values in where clause`...does it though? I don't know this specific library, but how would a PHP script know what you've put in your where clause in a string? Select the user by the username, and then use PHP to check if the retrieved password matches or not. (Also, retrieving by username and password isn't what you said before, which was to "find a user by his password" ...there was no mention of username. Please always be specific about what you are doing.).

Comment: Anyway best practice is to use `password_hash()` to hash, and `password_verify()` to verify afterwards. the [manual page for crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) even mentions this specifically

Comment: Do you think I should find a way to convert all users passwords to a new hashing (using password_hash()) ?

Comment: Ideally yes. You can't really "convert" them though, since they're hashed. All users would need to be asked to reset their password, once you've written a PHP page where they can go to set a new password, which would then be hashed using password_hash instead of crypt. Although as the documentation notes, hashes produced by password_hash may be compatible with crypt (and vice versa), so you might be able to get away with simply modifying the PHP code and not changing the existing hashes. You'll need to test it out.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about another way : when a user will login again, I could re-insert his actual password in a new column using password_hash(). Don't you think so ?

Comment: Yes you could do that, but you have to keep that code until everyone has logged in. It could get messy if that takes a long time to occur.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. About my initial question, is there a SQL function that can select my crypt() passwords in a where clause ? Sorry to insist....

Comment: Not as far as I know. You'd have to crypt() the password using PHP first before you put it into the WHERE clause so hopefully the result of that would match the hashed value in the DB and the query would return a result. But I must emphasise that is _not_ a recommended approach at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help. Anyway, even this bad approach doesn't work...